# Joomla homepage, adding a module as cta

Tags: joomla, module

I have been tasked to add 3 images to a homepage in Joomla.

The homepage already has 3 cta boxes and all i need to do is to add another 3 just below them, containing images.

The existing Call to actions seem to be modules, I tried creating one of its same type and assign the next available position, but it didn't work.

Any ideas of how to add them?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you published the module (at a position the template uses)? could you try to also add some text to the module so that we see if the text is shown or not...
(I assume you picked a module for "User content" (raw html)?)

Comment: Yes, also I tried assigning the position number 1, applied it and it did show in the homepage, but out of the place. Does a new position need to be added? The module selected was an html one.

Comment: What does "out of place"mean? Wrong position? But...did it show the image at all (at that wrong position)? Do you know the "tp=1"-switch to show the template-positions?

Comment: It showed on the homepage. But was not placed right under the 1st of the 3 existing ctas as I would expect. I don't know the "tp=1" switch

Comment: Try to append "&tp=1" to /index.php - it will show the template-positions. (If "Preview tp-pos" is enabled in Templates>Options) - maybe you can find a better position for the module there...

Comment: That won't work in newer Joomla unless you go to the template manager and turn on preview.

WHy are you using position-1? Is that the same position as the otehr modules?